# Create NetCDF file with irregular rotated lat-lon grid for QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, netcdf, panoply

I want to write data to a NetCDF file with an irregular rotated lat-lon coordinate grid and open it in QGIS. The data is on an irregular grid which follows a satellite swath. The grid is irregular in the sense that the distances between points can vary. Basically, I have a matrix of wind speed values ws10 at certain latitude and longitude coordinates. How do I properly save these ws10(lat, lon) to a NetCDF file, so that they can be viewed in QGIS projected on a world map?

This is what my NetCDF file header currently looks like:

```
netcdf waves {
dimensions:
        y = 52 ;
        x = 60 ;
variables:
        float lat(y, x) ;
                lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
                lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
                lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        float lon(y, x) ;
                lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
                lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
                lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        float ws10(y, x) ;
                ws10:long_name = "Wind Speed at 10 m" ;
                ws10:units = "meters per second" ;
                ws10:coordinates = "lon lat" ;
}
```

If I open the file in QGIS and add it as a raster or mesh layer (based on Dave X's comment) it takes the x-y-indices as coordinates. For some reason the grey-scale raster layer is flipped:
[image: QGIS screenshot]

Yet Panoply projects the raster as intended:
[image: Panoply screenshot]
Based on other questions, I have tried to add the CRS information to the file as shown below, but QGIS still uses the x-y-grid. How can this be solved?

```
netcdf test_man {
dimensions:
        y = 52 ;
        x = 60 ;
variables:
        int crs ;
                crs:spatial_ref = "GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS_84\",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]]" ;
                crs:grid_mapping_name = "latitude_longitude" ;
                crs:longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0. ;
                crs:semi_major_axis = 6378137. ;
                crs:inverse_flattening = 298.257223563 ;
        float lat(y, x) ;
                lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
                lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
                lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        float lon(y, x) ;
                lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
                lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
                lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        float ws10(y, x) ;
                ws10:long_name = "Wind Speed at 10 m" ;
                ws10:units = "meters per second" ;
                ws10:coordinates = "lon lat" ;
                ws10:grid_mapping = "crs" ;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `Layer/Add layer/Add Mesh layer'?

Comment: I have replaced the QGIS screenshot in the question. As you can see, it still uses x-y instead of lat-lon when added as a mesh layer. But I realize now that the raster layer (grey) is flipped vertically.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [UGRID Convention](https://ugrid-conventions.github.io/ugrid-conventions/) NetCDF format to be fully supported by QGIS Mesh Layer, where you need to define your grid elements. Examples can be found in [MDAL test suite](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL/tree/master/tests/data/ugrid). MDAL is C++ Library that QGIS uses to read the data for Mesh Layer.